# Unmanaged call - Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: vb.net, interop

I'm trying to call the following unmanaged dll and it returns an error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory

```
' this is the declare part
Declare Ansi Function GuestCard Lib "C:\proRFL.Dll" (ByVal fUSB As Byte, 
     ByVal dlsCoID As Long, ByVal CardNo As Integer, ByVal dai As Integer, 
     ByVal llock As Integer, ByVal pdoors As Integer, ByVal BTime As String, 
     ByVal ETime As String, ByVal LockNo As String, ByVal Buffer As String) As Integer
```

```
' this is the calling part
Dim st As Integer = GuestCard(flagUSB, CLng(dlsCoID), CInt(CardNo) Mod 16, CInt(dai) Mod 256, llock, pdoors, BTime, ETime, LockNo, bufHexStr)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please show the original unmanaged signature for `GuestCard`.

Comment: That is the problem. All i have is the dll file. I don't have the original code.

Comment: You don't have to have the orignal code, but the dll must come with a documentation of some sort or a c/c++ header, otherwise no one will know how to use it. If you don't even have that, then the question is how do you know the first parameter is a byte and the second is a long.

Comment: i have a sample code which will work in delphi7. What i do is just simply comvert the code while keeping the type in vb.

Comment: That's a VB6 declaration.  The dlsCoID is actually Integer, next 4 are Byte.  Buffer surely needs to be StringBuilder.  Don't use libraries that you can't get support for.

Comment: @HansPassant Not necessarily, in fact I rarely see VB6 API declarations with `Integer`s. Please post the Delphi declaration, Chung Pak Chin (the line with `external 'proRFL.Dll'`).

Comment: function GuestCard(fUSB:Byte;dlsCoID:Integer;CardNo,dai,llock,pdoors:Byte;BDate,EDate,RoomNo:Pchar;CardHexStr:PChar):Integer; stdcall;
    external 'proRFL.DLL';

Comment: Then try `Declare Ansi Function GuestCard Lib "C:\proRFL.Dll" (ByVal fUSB As Byte, ByVal dlsCoID As Integer, ByVal CardNo As Byte, ByVal dai As Byte, ByVal llock As Byte, ByVal pdoors As Byte, ByVal BTime As String, ByVal ETime As String, ByVal LockNo As String, ByVal Buffer As String) As Integer`. Do you allocate space in the `Buffer` before making the call?

Comment: i see the code in the delphi they make array of  128 space before make the call. but how to do so in vb?

something like this 
bufHexStr:    Array[0..128] of char;

Comment: In VB you either assign a value to the string that is long enough (e.g. 128 spaces) or declare the parameter as StringBuilder and make sure it has [required Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1h0a5sy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Public Shared bufHexStr As String = New String(CChar(" "), 128) 
added this code. but it's doesn't seem to do the trick. same error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I should declare the function in a module instead of a class. A simple yet stupid mistake. Thank you all for helping me out. @GSerg You are right about the type. Tank you.